# Media Player OnCompletion not working properly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I have tried playing a music from raw folder, it works completely. But when I try with URL, it gives me an error.

I have a problem where a music has ended then can't play it again when play button is clicked. I've given a Try Catch Exception but the detail error is not appears.

My Code :

```
class DetailAudioActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer
    private lateinit var handler: Handler
    private lateinit var runnable: Runnable
    private var isAudioPaused = true

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityDetailAudioBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

        prepareAudioPlayer()
    }

    private fun prepareAudioPlayer() {
        val urlFile = intent.getStringExtra("url_file")
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
        mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
            .build())
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(urlFile))
        mediaPlayer.prepare()

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener {
            setupAudioPlayer()
        }
    }

    private fun setupAudioPlayer() {
        runnable = Runnable {
            binding.seekbarAudio.progress = mediaPlayer.currentPosition
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500)
        }

        val duration = mediaPlayer.duration.toLong()
        val endDuration = convertFormat(duration)
        binding.endTime.text = endDuration

        binding.btnPlay.setOnClickListener {
            if (isAudioPaused) {
                isAudioPaused = false
                binding.btnPlay.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.btnPause.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                mediaPlayer.start()

                binding.seekbarAudio.max = mediaPlayer.duration
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0)
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.prepare()
            }
        }

        binding.btnPause.setOnClickListener {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
                isAudioPaused = true
                binding.btnPlay.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.btnPause.visibility = View.GONE

                mediaPlayer.pause()
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
            }
        }

        binding.seekbarAudio.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                if (fromUser) {
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress)
                }

                binding.startTime.text = convertFormat(mediaPlayer.currentPosition.toLong())
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {

            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {

            }
        })

        // Where a music has ended then button play is clicked, it gives me an error
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener {
            binding.btnPause.visibility = View.GONE
            binding.btnPlay.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(0)
        }
    }

    private fun convertFormat(duration: Long): String {
        return String.format(
            "%02d:%02d",
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(
                    duration
                )
            )
        )
    }
}
```

I hope you can support me with this.

Edit : Update an error

[image: 1]

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException sir, I've edited the question @snorlax

Comment: prepare(); is a blocking operation, if you dont want to block your UI Thread use prepareAsync();. Or use prepare in another Thread

Comment: still getting error use prepareAsync(). I've set in onCompletion isAudioPaused = true and the media player working normally. Thanks for the answer @snorlax